# C++: How to implement (something like) JSON

Tags: c++

Not sure how to explain it - I'm pretty new to C++, but... let me try:

Let's say I have 300+ names (Jeff, Jack...) with 300+ int values (0 or 1). In JS I would use JSON. Something like this:

```
var people = {"person": [
              {"name": "Jeff","val": 0},
              {"name": "Jill","val": 1},
              {"name": "Jack","val": 0},
              {"name": "Jim","val": 1},
              {"name": "John","val": 0}
]}
```

What's the best way to do this in C++? 
Thanks.

Comment: I would advise you against implementing **something like** JSON: use an existing library or implement the real JSON standard.

Comment: What is it you want?  A text representation of the data structure?  Or just writing a "literal" with that data?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to *store* or *parse* such data?

Comment: I think that OP wants C++ syntax for initialization that is easily legible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can have duplicate names you can't use a map, so you could use something like this:

```
struct Person
{
  Person( const std::string & n, int v ) : name(n), val(v) {}
  std::string name;
  int val;
};

int main()
{
std::vector<Person> people;

people.push_back( Person( "Jeff", 0 ) );
people.push_back( Person( "Jill", 1 ) );
...

}
```

If you wanted uniqueness of names you could do something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, int> people;
people["Jeff"] = 0;
people["Jill"] = 1;
```

or

```
std::map<std::string, Person> people;
people["Jeff"] = Person("Jeff",0);
people["Jill"] = Person("Jill",1);
```

If you're using this code a lot you can clean up the repeated cruft.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
struct BuildMap
{
  BuildMap() : map_() {}
  BuildMap<K,V>& operator()( const K & key, const V & value )
  {
    map_[key]=value;
    return *this;
  }
  std::map<K,V> operator()() { return map_; }
  std::map<K,V> map_;
};

std::map<std::string,int> people = BuildMap<std::string,int>()
  ( "Jeff", 0 )
  ( "Jill", 1 )
  ( "John", 1 )
  ();
```

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Or just use Boost.Assign for eased initialization.

Comment: @Georg : Awesome library, been looking for something like that for ages. Another handy boost util. Heres the link : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at jsoncpp - it is a lightweight json parser, that makes it very easy to use json in your c++ project.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/

Then you can create a text file, write some entries in the json format there and then open this file in your c++ program. There are plenty of tutorials of how to do it with jsoncpp.

Comment: Looks great, but I suck too much in C++ so I have no idea how to use/implement it. I just need an array(?) of 300+ unique words and values (1 or 0 ==> true/false) and be able to easily access it. In JS it's sooo easy - just create an object and access it by people.person[X].name... But thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at std::map.

link here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

It's an associative container that is similar to a dictionary. Something like this?

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<string,int> person;

void initPeople(){
    person["Jeff"] = 0;
    person["Jill"] = 1;
    person["Jack"] = 0;
    person["Jim"] = 1;
    person["John"] = 0;
}
```

Comment: That assumes that the names are unique, and that the original order doesn't matter.  The OP didn't specify this.

Comment: Names are unique, order doesn't matter. I just need to manually write it and access by random number - e.g. return people.person[rndnumber].name and return people.person[NOTrndnumber].val.